# VSTS 2015 Git Pull Requests description doesn't support markdown

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

We use VSTS 2015 and according to [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/overview) it should support markdown in pull requests, but it seems it doesn't.

I added small formatting like `# header` and code sections ```` ```xml ```` but it outputs plain text in the pull request comment section.

Any ideas? maybe I need to install a custom extension or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/2016/nov-23-team-services this feature is available in VSTS. You can comment in markdown in TFS 2017 and support for markdown in comments was added in TFS 2017 Update 1.

Update 1 for TFS 2017 is still in RC, but is Go-Live so you can use it in production. I would recommend that you import your collection to VSTS and reduce your risks and keep yourselves up to date: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts

Comment: So it seems its a VSTS 2017 feature. Documentation lead me to believe its in 2015 as well